How to generate and add ports as string in Yaml file using Java
I am facing a peculiar issue which I am not able to resolve. Not sure where I am going wrong.
Description - I have a JavaFX GUI. On GUI I have 2 input fields which accepts port number (string).
I have a java code which gets the data from the bean and creates yaml file with the configuration.
Code -
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.DumperOptions;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Service
public class GenerateYamlFileImpl implements GenerateYamlFile {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(GenerateYamlFileImpl.class);

    public void writeYamlfile(Container container, File file) {
        try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file.getPath() + LocalDateTime.now() + FXMLPageConstants.FILE_TYPE)) {
            DumperOptions options = new DumperOptions();
            options.setDefaultFlowStyle(DumperOptions.FlowStyle.BLOCK);
            options.setPrettyFlow(true);
            Yaml yaml = new Yaml(options);
            Map<String, Object> data = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            data.put("name", container.getName());

            Map<String, Object> topology = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            Map<String, Object> nodes = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            for (Map.Entry<String, NodesProperties> entry : container.getTopology().getNodes().entrySet()) {
                Map<String, Object> nodeDetails = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
                NodesProperties nodeProps = entry.getValue();
                nodeDetails.put("kind", nodeProps.getKind());
                nodeDetails.put("image", nodeProps.getImage());
                if (nodeProps.getGroup() != null && !nodeProps.getGroup().isBlank()) {
                    nodeDetails.put("group", nodeProps.getGroup());
                }
                if (nodeProps.getStartupConfig() != null && !nodeProps.getStartupConfig().isBlank()) {
                    nodeDetails.put("startup-config", nodeProps.getStartupConfig());
                }
                if (nodeProps.getPorts() != null && !nodeProps.getPorts().isEmpty()) {
                    String[] ports = nodeProps.getPorts().stream().map(port -> port+":"+"22").toArray(String[]::new);
                    nodeDetails.put("ports", ports);
                }
                nodes.put(entry.getKey(), nodeDetails);
            }
            topology.put("nodes", nodes);
            StringBuilder linksYaml = new StringBuilder();
            linksYaml.append("  links:\n");
            for (Link link : container.getTopology().getLinks()) {
                linksYaml.append("    - endpoints: [\"");
                linksYaml.append(String.join("\", \"", link.getEndpoints()));
                linksYaml.append("\"]\n");
            }
            topology.put("nodes", nodes);
            data.put("topology", topology);
            yaml.dump(data, writer);
            writer.write(linksYaml.toString());
            writer.flush();
            logger.info("YAML file generated successfully: ");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Error while writing YAML file", e);
        }
    }
}

public class Container {

    private String name;
    private Topology topology;

}

public class Topology {

    private Map<String, NodesProperties> nodes;
    private List<Link> links;
}

public class NodesProperties {

    private String kind;
    private String image;
    private List<String> ports;
    private String group;
    private String startupConfig;
}

public class Link {

    private List<String> endpoints;
}


With the above code I am able to achieve below config-
name: srlceostopo
topology:
  nodes:
    srl1:
      kind: nokia_srlinux
      image: ghcr.io/nokia/srlinux
      group: leaf
      ports:
      - '1000:22'
    ceos1:
      kind: ceos
      image: ceos:4.32.0.1F
      group: leaf
      ports:
      - '2000:22'
    srl2:
      kind: nokia_srlinux
      image: ghcr.io/nokia/srlinux
      group: leaf
      ports:
      - '3000:22'
  links:
    - endpoints: ["srl1:e1-1", "ceos1:eth1"]
    - endpoints: ["srl2:e1-1", "srl1:e1-2"]
    - endpoints: ["srl2:e1-2", "ceos1:eth3"]


Please note -
With one port, the config is generated fine.
ports:
- '2000:22'
But when I am trying to add 2 ports, the yaml file is breaking. Instead of reading it as string, it is reading it as numbers.
e.g.
ports:
- '2000:22
- 3000:80

This error causing issue while executing the yaml in other places.
Question - How can I update my code so that it can generate the configuration for  ports in String  i.e. with double quotes or single quotes
Please Note - Because of the issue, right now I have modified the GUI to accept only 1 port. I want to enable multiple ports and generate configurations accordingly.
I have alreaty tried with Representer, but I am not getting appropriate result with it.
`
 Representer representer = new Representer(options) {
                @Override
                protected Node representScalar(Tag tag, String value) {
                    // Ensure all scalar values are double-quoted
                    return super.representScalar(tag, value, DumperOptions.ScalarStyle.DOUBLE_QUOTED);
                }
            };
`
...
`
if (nodeProps.getPorts() != null && !nodeProps.getPorts().isEmpty()) {
                    List<String> ports = nodeProps.getPorts().stream()
                            .map(port -> "\"" + port + "\"")
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
                    nodeDetails.put("ports", ports);
                }
`

I want the code to generate yaml file with multiple ports in string format
ports:
- "2000:22"
- "3000:80"


Similar but different question on lists of stuff in yaml.  My answer there uses the jackson API for yaml serialization rather than snakeyaml directly, it might be applicable to your case, or might not.
